# Linked List Delete Node

Tags: c, linked-list

So I'm trying to implement a function that deletes nodes from a linked list.

Here's my main:

```
int main(void)
{
    NODE* first = generateNodes(5);
    NODE* jank = getNode(first, 2);
    deleteNode(first,2);
    printf("Length of Node List: %d\n",getNodeListLength(first));
    printf("First Node: %d\n",first -> pos); 
    printf("Jank Node: %d\n",jank -> pos); 
    return 0;
}
```

This is my output:

```
Length of Node List: 2
First Node: 0
Jank Node: 2
```

The output should be (because in `main()` I removed `jank`, and decreased the size of the linked list by one):

```
Length of Node List: 4
First Node: 0
Jank Node: NULL
```

Here's my entire source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* NODE STRUCTURE */

typedef struct node{

    char* thing;

    int pos; /* Index of node */
    struct node* next; /* Pointer to next node */

} NODE;

/* Generates a single node */ 
NODE* generateNode();

/* Generates linked nodes and returns the first node */
NODE* generateNodes(int num);

/* Gets a node at a certain index */
NODE* getNode(NODE* start, int index);

/* Returns the length of a list of nodes */
size_t getNodeListLength(NODE* start);

/* Removes a node at a certain index */
NODE* deleteNode(NODE* start, int index);

int main(void)
{
    NODE* first = generateNodes(5);
    NODE* jank = getNode(first, 2);
    deleteNode(first,2);
    printf("Length of Node List: %d\n",getNodeListLength(first));
    printf("First Node: %d\n",first -> pos); 
    printf("Other Node: %d\n",jank -> pos); 
    return 0;
}

NODE* generateNode()
{
    return (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
}

NODE* generateNodes(int num)
{
    NODE* one = generateNode();
    NODE* cpy = one;

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < num - 1; i++)
    {

        NODE* next = generateNode();
        cpy -> next = next;
        cpy -> pos = i;
        cpy = next;

    }

    cpy -> pos = i;
    cpy -> next = NULL;

    return one;
}

NODE* getNode(NODE* start, int index)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        start = start -> next;
    }
    return start;
}

size_t getNodeListLength(NODE* start)
{
    size_t i;
    while(start -> next != NULL)
    {
        start = start -> next;
        i++;
    }
    return i - 1;
}

NODE* deleteNode(NODE* start, int index)
{
    if(index > 0)
    {
        NODE* f = getNode(start,index - 1);
        NODE* l = getNode(start,index + 1);
        NODE* d = getNode(start,index);
        f -> next = l;
        free(d);
        return start;
    }
    if(index == 0)
    {
        NODE* up = start -> next;
        free(start);
        return up;
    }
    if(index + 1 == getNodeListLength(start))
    {
        NODE* r = getNode(start,index);
        NODE* c = getNode(start,index - 1);
        c -> next = NULL;
        free(r);
        return start;
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It may sometimes be helpful to specify what part of the code you are least comfortable does what it should, and look there with close attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I notice your `size_t i` in `getNodeListLength` is not initialized to any value - this could be the source of the unexpected size reporting.

Also, you remove `jank` from the list, but your `jank` pointer is still pointing to the node (even though it has been `free`'d) - this means using `jank` after that is accessing memory that is no longer yours!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
//modify this method
size_t getNodeListLength(NODE* start)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while(start != NULL)
    {
        start = start -> next;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my error was in this function:

```
size_t getNodeListLength(NODE* start)
{
    size_t i;
    while(start -> next != NULL)
    {
        start = start -> next;
        i++;
    }
    return i - 1;
}
```

should be:

```
size_t getNodeListLength(NODE* start)
{
    size_t i = 1;
    while(start -> next != NULL)
    {
        start = start -> next;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```